# Website works on Chrome, but not Firefox?

Tags: css, html

So, I have a problem; I think it has to do with either the HTML or CSS...
I was working on a website template, and... like..

I'll let the pictures explain it.

Chrome:  http://i57.tinypic.com/24qk51s.png

Firefox:  http://i57.tinypic.com/xgllyb.png

No idea what is going on; as this is my first website

```
<html>
```

(Ignore the 5,000 blockquotes at the bottom, LOL)

Comment: Just seeing the images how can we help you?  Definitely the problem in CSS. A clue I can give is to inspect you html elements using dev tools or firebug

Comment: Is that a single html page? In that case is it possible for you to share the code using JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @VamsiKrishna http://jsfiddle.net/d6Ma7/

Comment: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1812/firefox_2_prevent_automatic_image_resizing/ Please do this in your firefox. This is not the solution. But I just want to verify if it is the auto resize issue. Once that is confirmed we can set some relative size for images. I feel that is the issue.

Comment: Instead of hardcoded values like 960px, 935 px try to give those in percentages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your CSS file isn't loading on Firefox. This is likely because Firefox is more strict in parsing its HTML. Simply change this line:

`<link href="layout.css" type="syle/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

To this:

`<link href="layout.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

And it will probably work. My guess is that Chrome realizes that you want the link to point to a CSS file but Firefox does not.

Comment: Didn't even notice the typo; It's funny how things like that can destroy us, but yeah, even after fixing it to "Style" 'text' worked

Comment: Usually data types fall into several basic categories. `text` is one of them. The file is plain text. It should be treated as CSS, so `text/css`. Right? :]

Comment: I guess so, this is my first website/template I've ever created.